# How to catch click event of button of os x application through the applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, applescript-objc

We can click Mac os application `button` or `checkbox` by using applescript as an example:

```
click checkbox "Send" of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
```

Is it possible to catch click event of button of mac os application through the applescript or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an event listener. AppleScript only really has folder actions and they won't quite get you to where you need to go.

Without specific information on the application you are trying to catch click events for, it is hard to say whether or not it can be done. Some applications have built-in hooks for users to place scripts in the Application Support folder or /Library/app_name/scripts folder that get activated upon certain events.

In terms of listeners/watchers for general application events, here are a few good resources to check out:

[Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org)

[Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)